# mvc - date validation - data annotation - client validation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime, model-view-controller, client-side-validation

I use

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

to validate date input, but the validation only happens on server side, client side validation is not firing. Client side validation works for other data annotations like required, or mas length but not for date.

I set globalization on web config too. 
any idea?

Comment: If I remember correctly, data type and display format need to be on their own separate lines...

Comment: Most often this is due to the format mismatch from client and server. If you can try mentioning the format in your page date picker or from wherever this data comes, you might be able to understand the problem.

Comment: I deleted the display format part, now it checks as us date, but still validation occurs on server not on client, any idea?